# Liverpool FC results with FILTER function

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with the raw data of the EPL results. I need to convert the table from the first screen to the table from the second screen. The basis for the formula should be built through the FILTER function. File link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rwCqIDMc9-7kq-tMUN1O9WbxaymDew63ev0GOxRRfKk/edit#gid=1595719136

- The "Liverpool" opponents must be placed in the same column. Replace the "Liverpool" name with "H" or "A" depending on which column the name is located in
- The score inside the XG and Score columns should also change depending on which column "Liverpool" is in (if "Liverpool" is in column B of the Data sheet, then the score does not change, if it is in column C, then it does)

Final version have to look like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKyL7.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,map('Data sheet'!A:A,'Data sheet'!B:B,'Data sheet'!C:C,'Data sheet'!D:D,'Data sheet'!E:E,'Data sheet'!F:F,'Data sheet'!G:G,lambda(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,if(a="",,{a,index(if(b=A1,{"H",c,d,e,f,g},if(c=A1,{"A",b,e,d,g,f},)))}))),
       filter(Σ,(index(Σ,,2)<>"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I donate some money to you for your help?